# Sell enterprise iPhone app from company to company

Tags: iphone, distribution, enterprise

Is it possible for a company to sell and inhouse app to an other company? 
So, my company develops an app for inhouse use in an other company. How would we deploy this?

Comment: @homas Van Nuffel: You should improve your question heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sign it and depoloy it using your client's certificate they can get from Apple's developer site. They can revoke the certificate anytime, so I don't see a downside of them handing you the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

It can now through the Volume Purchase Program
http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

Look down to "get Custom B2B apps"

it's not easy - and customers are restricted to certain US companies, only, but it is a start